# Perfect forward function and args into lambda

Tags: c++

Does this look like a idiomatic decent solution or there is a better approach

```
template <typename F, typename ... Args>
auto f(F&& f, Args&& ... args) {
    return [args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args) ...)]() mutable {
        return std::apply([](auto&& f, auto&& ... args) {
            forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
            }, std::move(args));
};
```

Comment: Lot of `f`: `f(F&& f)` + the one from lambda...

Comment: `forward` inside the lambda implies it will be called at most once, is that correct?

Comment: I do not like question "can this be done better" with code only. Without detailed context it is hard to tell how much better issue can be addressed. Since question is poorly stated it is hard to tell if this is over engineering of the beginner, or advanced developer which didn't pay annotation [ask] a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `tuple` for this: (and even if you use it, no reason to include the function itself into it)

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
auto foo(F &&f, Args &&... args)
{
    return [f = std::forward<F>(f), ...args = std::forward<Args>(args)]() mutable -> decltype(auto)
    {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        // Or without invoke:
        // return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
};
```

Also the return type of the lambda should be `decltype(auto)` to correctly handle returning references.

---

Also this is effectively a subset of `std::bind_front`, so unless you're doing this for practice, prefer that.

Comment: Dropping `std::apply`/`std::invoke` make this less universal. For example if `f` is member function pointer.

Comment: Didn't check it, but I think `std::bind_front` will not work with only moveable arguments, since it function object must be copyable.

Comment: @MarekR OP's code didn't have `std::invoke` either, and `std::apply` wouldn't help with member pointers. I'll mention `invoke`. *"since it function object must be copyable"* Why do you think it must be copyable?

Comment: Reason I suspect this problem since `std::function` has this issue and [std::move_only_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function) was introduced in C++23

Comment: @MarekR bind family normally captures by value, unless `std::ref` or `std::cref` is used to pass in the arguments. This is specifically safer for rvalues. Because if the result is stored, rvalues die before function object is called. Maybe an `extend` template with similar syntax to `std::forward` should be defined to choose by-value, vs by-left-ref.

Comment: @MarekR `std::function` can't handle move-only types because it's type-erased. One has to decide if it's copyable or not without knowing what callable will be inserted into it, and then you either crash at runtime when trying to copy a non-copyable callable, or refuse to accept it in the constructor at compile-time (which is what `std::function` does). `bind_front` doesn't have this issue because it's not type-erased. Here's a small demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nWKPe1ef4

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I rethought your point before receiving your comment. That's why it's deleted.